# Apache 2.4 - need to block a range but allow one IP address from the same range

Tags: apache, ip-blocking

I need to block a range of IP addresses in the /etc/apache2/ipblacklist.conf

The block is on 171.0.0.0/8
I do need to allow one IP address from the same range - 171.3.2.25/32

Trying to set it as below doesn't work - no matter the order. Each separate statement works fine

```
Require not ip 171.0.0.0/8
Require ip 171.3.2.25/32
```

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after consulting couple of friends, the answer to do so is to break the allow/deny into separate blocks

```
<RequireAny>
<RequireAll>
    Require ip 171.3.2.25/32
</RequireAll>
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not ip 171.0.0.0/8
</RequireAll>
</RequireAny>
```